# How to use Exclude in FluentAssertions for property in collection?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I have two classes:

```
public class ClassA
{
  public int? ID {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<ClassB> Children {get; set;}
}

public class ClassB
{
  public int? ID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I want to use fluent assertions to compare to ClassA instances. However I want to ignore the IDs (because the IDs will have been assigned after the save).

I know I can do this:

```
expectedA.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(actualA, options => options.Excluding(x => x.PropertyPath == "Children[0].ID"));
```

Which I can obviously repeat for each ClassB in the collection. However I'm looking for a way to exclude the all the IDs (rather than doing an exclude for each element).

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361521/how-do-i-exclude-a-property-of-all-items-in-ienumerable-when-using-shouldbeequiv) however if I remove the [0] indexers the assertions fail.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

What about?

```
expected.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(actualA, options => options.Excluding(su => 
   (su.RuntimeType == typeof(ClassB)) && (su.PropertyPath.EndsWith("Id")));`
```

Or you could do a RegEx match on the property path, such as

```
expected.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(actualA, options => options.Excluding(su => (Regex.IsMatch
   ("Children\[.+\]\.ID"));
```

I actually like that last one, but the regex stuff makes it a bit difficult to read. Maybe I should extend `ISubjectInfo` with a method to match the path against a wildcard pattern, so that you can do this:

```
expected.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(actualA, options => options
  .Excluding(su => su.PathMatches("Children[*].ID")));
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this one as the answer as the regex in an extension method is the approach I went with in the end

Comment: How has this changed in more recent versions of FluentAssertions? I'm not sure `PropertyPath` is still there

Comment: I tried both options without success, but was able to fix RegEx option to work with current version - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142576/how-to-use-exclude-in-fluentassertions-for-property-in-collection/51858245#51858245 . By the way, the new name for PropertyPath is SelectedMemberPath

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch(x.SelectedMemberPath, @"Children\[\d+\]\.ID")`

Comment: FluentAssertions v6 removed SelectedMemberPath the solution here is:
options => options.Excluding((IMemberInfo x) => x.DeclaringType == typeof(ClassB) && x.Path.EndsWith("Id"))

Comment: `SelectedMemeberPath` was renamed to `Path` in v.6.0.0: https://fluentassertions.com/releases/#600

Answer (score 39):

I've just come across a similar problem and the latest version of FluentAssertions has changed things a bit.

My objects contains dictionaries of other objects. The objects in the dictionaries contain other objects that I want to exclude. The scenario I have is around testing Json serialization where I ignore certain properties.

This works for me:

```
gotA.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedB , config => 
  config
    .Excluding(ctx => ctx.SelectedMemberInfo.MemberType == typeof(Venue))
    .Excluding(ctx => ctx.SelectedMemberInfo.MemberType == typeof(Exhibit))
    .Excluding(ctx => ctx.SelectedMemberInfo.MemberType == typeof(Content))
    .Excluding(ctx => ctx.SelectedMemberInfo.MemberType == typeof(Survey))
    .Excluding(ctx => ctx.SelectedMemberInfo.MemberType == typeof(Media))
  );
```

Took some time to work out how to do it, but it's really useful!

Comment: For what it is worth, you can also pass in an anonymous object as the expectation since FA 5 and include only the properties you care about.

Answer (score 28):

This is supported by [FluentAssertions 6.7](https://fluentassertions.com/releases/#670)

```cs
actualA.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedA, options =>
    options
       .For(a => a.Children)
       .Exclude(b => b.ID));
```

Comment: I know this is an old question but this answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 17):

Simple way would be to set assertions on collection directly, combined with its exclusion on `ClassA` equivalency assertion:

```
expectedA.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedB,
   o => o.Excluding(s => s.PropertyInfo.Name == "Children"));
expectedA.Children.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedB.Children,
   o => o.Excluding(s => s.PropertyInfo.Name = "Id"));
```

Comment: I think Propertyinfo does no longer exist. SelectedMemberInfo.Name should do it instead.

Answer (score 11):

There are a few valid answers here, but I am adding another one that does not involve stringly-typed expressions.

```
expectedA.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedB, o => o.Excluding(s => s.Children));
expectedA.Children.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedB.Children, o => o.Excluding(s => s.Id));
```

Answer (score 8):

The `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` method seems to be obsolete now, in order to get path for the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22182258) you can use the `Excluding` overload with `IMemberInfo.SelectedMemberPath` instead:

```
expected.Should().BeEquivalentTo(actualA, options => 
    options.Excluding((IMemberInfo mi) => mi.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("ID")));
```

Answer (score 7):

```
actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected,
  assertionOptions => assertionOptions
    .Excluding(x => x.CreationTimestamp))
```

BUT if you work with structs and class overriding equals, then you should change the default comparing with ComparingByMembers
https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/#value-types

```
actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected,
  assertionOptions => assertionOptions
    .Excluding(x => x.CreationTimestamp)
    .ComparingByMembers<T>())
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on  RegEx match idea from [Dennis Doomen‘s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22182258/52277) I was able to make it working

```
expected.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(actualA, options =>
  options.Excluding(su => 
     (Regex.IsMatch(su.SelectedMemberPath, "Children\\[.+\\].ID"));
```

Difference with Dennis answer: passing su.SelectedMemberPath, double back slashes to escape square brackets.

Comment: `SelectedMemeberPath` was renamed to `Path` in v.6.0.0 https://fluentassertions.com/releases/#600

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is:

```cs
expected.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(actual, config => config.ExcludingMissingMembers());
```

Comment: OP asked to exclude some existing (NOT Missing) members.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks the syntax is something like

```
       actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(
        expected, 
        config => config.Excluding(o => o.Id).Excluding(o => o.CreateDateUtc) });
```

Answer (score 0):

An extension class where you can pass a list of expressions

```
public static class FluentAssertionsExtensions {
    public static EquivalencyAssertionOptions<T> ExcludingNextProperties<T>(
        this EquivalencyAssertionOptions<T> options,
        params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] expressions) {
        foreach (var expression in expressions) {
            options.Excluding(expression);
        }

        return options;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, 
            config => config.ExcludingNextProperties(
                o => o.Id, 
                o => o.CreateDateUtc))
```